# How to write latex into a snippet code in Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: latex, markdown, jupyter, code-snippets

I am trying to write the following pseudocode:

```
while A  $\neq \emptyset$
   Something that includes latex symbols or notation 
end while
```

However inside of the snippet of code latex does not show up correctly. I have tried with $ single and doubles, but shows something weird like "@@@0@@@".

I am running on OS Sierra.

Comment: What kind of cell are you using for your pseudocode? This should work in Markdown cells.

Comment: Yes, I am using Markdown cells, but it seems that when I activate the snippet of code latex don't work. When I use the $ outputs something weird like  "@@0@@"

Comment: "Outputting something weird" is a different problem than "not showing up". It's probably a font issue. What operating system are you using?

Comment: Your right, let me update the question. I am using OS SIerra.